# Setting different variable types and bounds using LpVariable.dicts

Tags: python, pulp

I have a linear programming problem where I am trying to find the optimal set of investments to maximize net present value subject to a budget constraint. Most of these investment decisions are integer (0/1) but a few of them can be partially funded (continuous between 0 and 1). I am using PuLP in python and have set the decisions as a dictionary variable x rather than having a different variable corresponding to the decision for every variable. I am not sure how to assign categories to x using LpVariable.dicts so that the category for the integer variables is Integer and for the partially fundable variables is Continuous.

I have a dictionary Integer/Continuous strings saved as variable 'types' and a variable 'items' containing dictionary keys.

```
# Define dictionary keys
gc1=dict(zip(data['Investment ID'], data['Cost']))
items = list(gc1.keys())

# Define variable types
types=dict(zip(data['Investment ID'], np.where(data['Partial']==1, 'Continuous', 'Integer')))

# Define lp variable
x = LpVariable.dicts('x', items, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=types)
```

The optimization runs successfully, however some of the decisions that should be integer (0/1) are continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the `LpVariable.dicts()` method can only accept a single category - i.e. it can be used to generate a dictionary of variables which are all the same type.

Your options are either to create 2 lists - a list of continuous and a list of integer variables and then use `LpVariable.dicts()` method - or as shown below just instantiate variables one at a time which is still very easy using python list comprehension. As you can see all of the Integer variables are 1 or 0.

```
from pulp import *
import numpy as np

n_vars = 6
np.random.seed(0)

# Define some variable names and types
var_names = ['var_' + str(i) for i in range(n_vars)]
Partial = np.random.randint(2, size=n_vars)
types = np.where(Partial==1, 'Continuous', 'Integer')

# Create some returns
returns = np.random.rand(n_vars)

# Create some costs
costs = np.random.rand(n_vars)

# Allocate a budget
budget = 2.0

# Create list of contiuous variables
x_cont = [LpVariable(i, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=j) for i, j in zip(var_names, types)]

# Do an optimisation to check its worked:
prob = LpProblem("Mixed Problem", LpMaximize)
prob += lpSum([x_cont[i]*returns[i] for i in range(n_vars)])
prob += lpSum([x_cont[i]*costs[i] for i in range(n_vars)]) <= budget
prob.solve()

x_soln = np.array([x_cont[i].varValue for i in range(n_vars)])

print("costs: ", costs)
print("returns: ", returns)

print("types: ", types)
print("x_soln: ", x_soln)
```

Output:

```
costs:  [0.38344152 0.79172504 0.52889492 0.56804456 0.92559664 0.07103606]
returns:  [0.54488318 0.4236548  0.64589411 0.43758721 0.891773   0.96366276]
types:  ['Integer' 'Continuous' 'Continuous' 'Integer' 'Continuous' 'Continuous']
x_soln:  [1.         0.11497788 1.         0.         1.         1.        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @kabdulla! I also found another way to do this where you first set one category in LpVariable and then define the category for each element of the variable:

```
# Define dictionary keys
gc1=dict(zip(data['Investment ID'], data['Cost']))
items = list(gc1.keys())

# Define variable types
types=dict(zip(data['Investment ID'], np.where(data['Partial']==1, 'Continuous', 'Integer')))

# Define lp variable
x = LpVariable.dicts('x', items, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat='Integer')
for i in items:
     x[i].cat=types[i]
```

Comment: Nice! If you think this might be generally useful you could look under the hood of pulp code and consider adding support for the `.dicts()` method directly accepting an array of categories:   https://github.com/coin-or/pulp.  I think your example suggests this could be done quite easily.